# Changes not showing up when changing a file in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I have a file in my resources/lang folder and when I made a change to it, it didn't show up on my site.

I've tried `php artisan cache:clear`, `php artisan config:clear`, `php artisan view:clear`, but still no change

Comment: php artisan queue:restart i think

Comment: no that didn't work

Answer (score 1):

Try to clear `views` folder in `Project/storage/framework`. It might be an issue.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried your site on another browser ?

Comment: I tried a different browser and still nothing